# Setting rendered response into a variable twig Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a controller function which return a response with a  value, and I want to call this controller from twig so I use:

```
 {% render "UaePortailBundle:Note:isRempli" with { 'module_id' : module.id , 'year' : year } %}
```

the problem is that I want to set this returned value into a variable "x"

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
 {% set x = {% render "UaePortailBundle:Note:isRempli" with { 'module_id' : module.id , 'year' : year } %} %}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/set.html), you can do:

```
{% set x %}
    {% render "UaePortailBundle:Note:isRempli" with { 'module_id' : module.id , 'year' : year } %}
{% endset %}
```

Comment: then how can i access the properties if the action returning doctrine object.

Comment: I don't understand your question. A symfony action **must** return a response.